# Cron Expression Format: `*` and `?`

Tags: cron

I have just been reading [this](https://flylib.com/books/en/2.65.1/the_cron_expression_format.html) about the Cron Expression Format:

> **The ? Character**
>
> The question mark (?) character can be used only in the `dayofmonth` and `dayofweek` fields, but not at the same time. You can think of the `?` character as "I don't care what value is in this field." This is different from the asterisk, which indicates every value for the field. The `?` character says that no value was specified for this field.
>
> The reasons a value can't be specified for both fields are tough to explain and even tougher to understand. Basically, if a value was specified for each, the meaning would become ambiguous: Consider if an expression had the value 11 in a field for the day of the month and a value of WED in the field for the day of the week. Should that trigger fire only on the 11th of the month if it falls on a Wednesday? Or should it fire on both the 11th and every Wednesday? The ambiguity is removed by not allowing a value in both fields at the same time.
>
> Just remember that if you specify a value in one of the two fields, you must put a ? in the other.
>
> Example expression:
>
> ```
> 0 10,44 14 ? 3 WED
> ```

Just wondering: how can I now create a Cron job that does something on Friday 13th (like formatting my data partition) or Saturday 14th (like making a new backup)?

Comment: Good explanation on Cron expressions here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12058_01/doc/doc.1014/e12030/cron_expressions.htm

Comment: So from the link above, I believe the expression would be `0 0 12 13 * 5` (which should be every Friday (5) the 13th (13)  of every (*) month at noon (12)(0)(0)).  But I'm just starting to learn this stuff!

Comment: Circling back to this... NCron would be: `0 0 12 13 * F` https://ncrontab.swimburger.net/

Answer (score 0):

```
##########################################################
#        minute (0-59),
#        hour (0-23),
#        day of the month (1-31),
#        month of the year (1-12),
#        day of the week (0-6 with 0=Sunday).
##########################################################
# this is friday the 13th at 0:00 i guess?
# daynr:13 and dayname: friday 
0 0 13 * 4 /script.cgi
```